Trading in IRA account
When we trade using IRA account, as it is not taxable, any short or long term gains doesnt matter correct? And after retirement age when we withdraw money, there will not be a capital gains and losses list separated to short or long term but we will simply be taxed to whatever our then tax rate correct? I mean I hop we will not need to make a list of all the trades we did in many  years when we withdraw money during retirement.

Correct - Any qualified withdrawals from a Traditional IRA (i.e. not a Roth IRA) are taxed as ordinary income, regardless of holding period, cost basis, etc. There is no reason to track trades for tax purposes.
There is also no reason to track trades within a Roth IRA, since qualified withdrawals are not taxed at all. Roth IRAs are funded with money that was already subject to tax, so there's no capital gains tax involved that would necessitate tracking trades, holding periods, cost basis, etc.

Sorry I didnt understand the difference for Roth IRA. I thought it is the same except when you withdraw your own contribution only that one is not taxed.

No, earnings are not taxed either if they meet the exclusion criteria. My main point was that you don't have to worry about short-term/long-term in Roth IRAs either since you didn't specify Traditional in  your question.

ok so when trading with traditional or roth ira, i dont have to worry about trading too much, there is no short term long term or a list of trades we have to make at retirement age

Some IRA administrators may place limits on trading frequency, just as some 401k administrators do. Read the literature. I would argue that, except for rebalancing to stay on strategy, you should not be actively trading with retirement funds.
